# Facebook likebox and Twitter feed are blank on second view in Meteor app

Tags: facebook, twitter, meteor, facebook-javascript-sdk, iron-router

I have put a Facebook likebox and a Twitter feed into my Meteor app's homepage. The first time you navigate there, it works fine. But if you leave the page (while staying on the site), and then return, they are blank. This happens on multiple browsers and on Mac and PC.

I am using Iron Router, and Twitter template code like this:

```
<template name="twitter_feed">
    <div class="news-box">
        <a class="twitter-timeline" href="..." data-widget-id="..."></a>
    </div>
</template>
```

with javascript:

```
Template.twitter_feed.rendered = function () {
    !function(d,s,id){
        var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
            js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;
            js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }
    }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
}
```

(It's the same if I put the javascript into the template directly using `<script>`.)

How can I fix this? Here's the site if it helps: [Signup Zone](https://signup.zone/#news).

Thanks!

Comment: One simple solution that works for the Facebook likebox is to use the `iframe` version of the likebox code.  Unfortunately I can't find a Twitter equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't need any scripting.

1. Use the `iframe` version of the Facebook likebox code.
2. For Twitter, there is no `iframe` version.  But we can make one by putting its anchor `<a>` tag in its own `html` document, and then including an `iframe` to that.

Eg. for my Meteor app, I have put this `twitter.html` into `public`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Twitter timeline</title>
  <style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <a class="twitter-timeline" href="..." data-widget-id="..."></a>
  <script>
    !function(d,s,id){
        var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
            js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;
            js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }
    }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I have replaced the `twitter_feed` template with this:

```
<template name="twitter_feed">
    <div class="news-box">
        <iframe src="/twitter.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
                style="border: none; overflow:hidden; width:404px; height:650px; float:right"
                allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div>
</template>
```

And now it shows fine on second and subsequent views.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem for site that loads content in AJAX.
You need to manually force those widgets to re-parse the page. One workaround could be using jQuery to regenerate the Facebook likebox and Twitter feed each time content changes. Another hack would be setTimeout as follow:

```
Template.home.rendered = function() {
   setTimeout(function() { 
     twttr.widgets.load(this.firstNode);;
     FB.XFBML.parse(this.firstNode);
  }, 0);
}
```

Reference:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/cannot-update-tweet-button-with-ajax/16989
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: Thanks - could you give some more detail on the jQuery workaround?